# VBA Error 1101: Value Not Valid

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

This code opens a bunch of MS Project 2016 documents and dumps the contents into an Excel 2016 sheet. The MS Project file paths are in the range (rng2) C2:C & Last Row. Each time through, the 1101 error is thrown when it reaches the sixth item in the range. Fails at PrjApp.FileOpenEx rng2.

- The error occurs no matter how the file paths are ordered in the
  range.
- The code runs to completion when file paths are tested 1 at a
  time, so I know the paths and files are good.
- A watch shows that the rng2 value is exactly what it should be at time of failure (e.g. the value is set to the desired file path).

This makes no sense to me, but there must be something wrong with the code. Any ideas?

```
Sub OpenProjectCopyPasteData()

Dim PrjApp      As MSProject.Application
Dim aProg       As MSProject.Project
Dim PrjFullName As String
Dim t           As Task
Dim rngClr     As Range
Dim rngClr2     As Range
Dim rng         As Range
Dim rng2        As Range
Dim ws1         As Worksheet
Dim ws2         As Worksheet
Dim MyCell      As Variant
Dim Lastrow     As Long


Set ws1 = Worksheets("MS Project Milestones")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Active NRE Projects")
Set rngClr = ws1.Range("A:G")

Set PrjApp = New MSProject.Application

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ws1.Activate

'Clear current contents of Project Data tab
rngClr.ClearContents

'Open MS Project file
ws2.Activate

Set rng2 = Sheets("Active NRE Projects").Range("C2")
Do Until IsEmpty(rng2.Value)

PrjApp.FileOpenEx rng2
Set aProg = PrjApp.ActiveProject

' show all tasks
OutlineShowAllTasks

ws1.Activate

'Copy the project columns and paste into Excel
SelectTaskColumn Column:="Name"
EditCopy
Set ws1 = Worksheets("MS Project Milestones")
Set rng = ws1.Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

SelectTaskColumn Column:="Resource Names"
EditCopy
Set rng = ws1.Range("B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

SelectTaskColumn Column:="Finish"
EditCopy
Set rng = ws1.Range("F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

SelectTaskColumn Column:="Text1"
EditCopy
Set rng = ws1.Range("C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

SelectTaskColumn Column:="Text2"
EditCopy
Set rng = ws1.Range("D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

With Sheets("MS Project Milestones")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        Lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        Lastrow = 1
    End If
End With

With Sheets("MS Project Milestones")
        .Range("A" & (Lastrow + 1)).Value = "X"
        .Range("B" & (Lastrow + 1)).Value = "X"
        .Range("C" & (Lastrow + 1)).Value = "X"
        .Range("D" & (Lastrow + 1)).Value = "X"
        .Range("F" & (Lastrow + 1)).Value = "X"
End With

PrjApp.FileClose False
'PrjApp.Quit pjDoNotSave
'Set PrjApp = Nothing

ws2.Activate
Set rng2 = rng2.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

' reset settings of Excel and MS-Project
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'PrjApp.FileClose False
PrjApp.Quit pjDoNotSave
Set PrjApp = Nothing

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you point out which line you get the error on? Is it always the same line?

Comment: It doesn't matter which specific line. Rather, it seems to be when it hits the sixth item in the range. To test, I started the range at c3,c4,c5 etc. I also tried re-writing the loop with a defined range...no dice.

Comment: Can you point out which line of **code** that you get the error on.

Comment: No, @ERKSMTY it very much matters which specific line.

Comment: Ha! Sorry guys... It fails at PrjApp.FileOpenEx rng2

Comment: If this is happening on the 6th file, no matter what order the files are in, it sounds like a memory problem.  Try correctly qualifying your MSProject methods with the `PrjApp` application (so `PrjApp.OutlineShowAllTasks`, etc) - not specifying it may be causing issues.

Comment: @YowE3K You're a genius. Why did this work?

Comment: I'm guessing but I suspect that Excel would have had to have created a default instance of the Project Application object and was using that when you didn't tell it to use the Application object you created.  And your files were being opened in one application, and your methods were being run in another.  Goodness knows what that would have been doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to always specify which Application object you are using.

So change your unqualified references to the `OutlineShowAllTasks`, `SelectTaskColumn` and `EditCopy` methods so that they explicitly refer to your `PrjApp` Application object, e.g.

```
PrjApp.OutlineShowAllTasks
'...
PrjApp.SelectTaskColumn Column:="Name"
PrjApp.EditCopy
'... etc
```

---

Even if it didn't avoid memory and referencing issues, explicitly specifying the application makes it easier for someone else to understand your code - by including the `PrjApp.` they can easily see that things such as `OutlineShowAllTasks` are MSProject methods, and they don't spend time looking through your Excel code looking for a `Sub OutlineShowAllTasks()` (which is what I did when I first saw your code).

Comment: So qualifying the references definitely helped, but now the issue has returned. Not sure how relevant this is, but I can't see the individual project workbooks opening/closing as the code loops through them. Is it possible that the workbooks aren't being properly opened/closed, and that's causing a memory shortage?

Comment: @ERKSMTY If you insert a `PrjApp.Visible = True` statement after your `Set PrjApp = New MSProject.Application` statement then you will be able to see the Project application.  Otherwise it just runs in the background.  I'm beginning to think this wasn't a memory issue at all - I just googled `project vba error 1101` and found [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/242723/error-message-when-macro-assigns-material-resource-to-a-task-run-time-error-1101.-the-argument-value-is-not-valid) which implies it might be a data issue.

Comment: Thanks for the 'PrjApp.Visible' tip. I'm struggling to understand how this could be a data issue if the code can process each file in the range if run individually.

Comment: @ERKSMTY I'm not sure how it can be a data issue either (especially as it is on the file open), but I can't see anything else in your code that could be causing a memory issue.  All I can suggest is that you step through your code and, when it crashes, try manually opening the file that it crashed at - it may produce a more meaningful message if it thinks it is a human doing the open instead of a program doing it.  (Unfortunately, not having MSProject myself, I can't play around and try to replicate the issue.)

Comment: It must've been a data issue. I can't figure out exactly what, because it looks like all of the data types are consistent across the project notebooks. However, I switched `rng2` from `range` to `variant`, and that seemed to fix (at least for the moment haha). Thanks again for your time and energy. Do you mind me asking what you do for a living and what industry you work in?

Comment: @ERKSMTY (a) I was thinking of a data issue in the Project file, not in the Excel file (b) If `rng2` was declared as a `Variant`, it would be set as a `Variant/Range` by the `Set rng2 = Sheets("Active NRE Projects").Range("C2")` statement, so I'm not sure how that would have helped any (but I am certainly glad if it did work!) (c) I work in the actuarial area of an insurance company